# EF core trying to update table I have not specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class called BasketItem

```
public class BasketItem
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketItemId { get; set; }

    public Product Product {get;set;}

    public Basket Basket {get; set; }

}
```

Within there, there's a reference to two other classes. Product and Basket.

```
public class Basket
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketId { get; set; }

    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
}
```

Basket contains an Id and a reference to IdentityUser

However, I get this exception when I run the code.
[image: Exception]

I do not understand why it is trying to update the IdentiyUser table with a duplicate account, I am only trying to update the BasketItem table.

Initial calling code

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Add(int productId)
{
    string userId = userManager.GetUserId(User);
    IdentityUser identityUser = await accountManager.GetCurrentUserAsync(userId);
    Basket basket = await basketManager.GetUserBasketAsync(identityUser);

    await basketManager.AddProductToBasketAsync(productId, basket);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Call to account manager:

```
public async Task<IdentityUser> GetCurrentUserAsync(string accountId)
{
    if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountId) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountId)))
        return await accountRepository.GetCurrentUserAsync(accountId);
    else throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

Account repo

```
public async Task<IdentityUser> GetCurrentUserAsync(string accountId)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == accountId).FirstOrDefault());
    return await task;
}
```

Basket manager call

```
public async Task<Basket> GetUserBasketAsync(IdentityUser identityUser)
{
    if (identityUser != null)
        return await basketRepository.GetUserBasketAsync(identityUser);
    else throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Basket repo call

```
public async Task<Basket> GetUserBasketAsync(IdentityUser identityUser)
{
    //Include method returns related Entity. 
    var task = Task.Run(() => context.Basket.Include(x => x.IdentityUser).Where(x => x.IdentityUser.Id == identityUser.Id).SingleOrDefault());
    return await task;
}
```

Basket add manager call

```
public async Task<int> AddProductToBasketAsync(int productId, Basket basket)
{
    if (basket == null)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    Product product = await productManager.GetProductByIdAsync(productId);

    if (product == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not retrieve product");

    return await basketRepository.AddProductToBasketAsync(product, basket);
}
```

Product manager call

```
public async Task<Product> GetProductByIdAsync(int? id)
{
    return await productRepository.GetProductByIdAsync(id);
}
```

Product repo call

```
public async Task<Product> GetProductByIdAsync(int? id)
{
    return await context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ProductId == id);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for the entire call (from the Controller action to the method posted). How are you creating the product and basket variables? What values do they have when it gets to the `AddProductToBasketAsync` method?

Comment: Is there a chance EF thinks `basket` and it's associated are completely new entities? As a test, instead of setting `basketItem.Basket` consider adding a `BasketId` property and setting that instead.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added everything, it's a bit messy hence my initial exclusion. When debugging the Basket and Product entities are fully populated with the correct information

Comment: @DavidG I will give that a try

Comment: Is your `BasketItemId` an AUTO_INCREMENT field? Please check.

Comment: @Haytam Yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Entity Framework is not seeing the `ApplicationUser` as an already existing entity. I would suggest you to be explicit in your models and do not let it decide for itself:

```
public class BasketItem
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketItemId { get; set; }

    // add the actual columns
    public int ProductId { get; set; }    
    public int BaskedId { get; set; }

    public Product Product {get;set;}
    public Basket Basket {get; set; }
}

public class Basket
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketId { get; set; }

    // I believe it's a string but it could be a System.Guid instead
    public string IdentityUserId { get; set; }

    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
}
```

This could also be happening due to the incorrect use of the Task Parallel Library in `GetUserBasketAsync`. I would suggest you to remove the call to `Task.Run` and instead use the methods provided by Entity Framework which are correctly asynchronous:

```
// async modifier not needed here
public Task<Basket> GetUserBasketAsync(IdentityUser identityUser)
{
    //Include method returns related Entity. 
    return context.Basket
        .Include(x => x.IdentityUser)
        .Where(x => x.IdentityUser.Id == identityUser.Id)
        // use the asynchronous version instead of the synchronous one
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Notice that the same issue occurs on `GetCurrentUserAsync`, so modify it accordingly:

```
public Task<IdentityUser> GetCurrentUserAsync(string accountId)
{
    return context.Users
        .Where(x => x.Id == accountId)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds feasible. I will do this.